# VBA passing range through a function

Tags: excel, vba, range

I have a question regarding VBA range reference.

I am writing a code to export table data to a normal range. For some reason, I cannot assign the range to my range variable. With this code, I have run-time error :91. Object variable not set.

From the error message I get the idea that my code is not done. I need to do something more about it. So the range can be properly set.

I was wondering what is missing here. It is a range = range situation to me.

Here is my code:

```
Function selecttable() As Range

'Intialize variables.
Dim objLB As ListObject, tablename() As String
Dim i As Integer, rng As Range

i = 1

'read through all tables in the sheet.

For Each objLB In ActiveSheet.ListObjects

ReDim Preserve tablename(1 To i + 1) ' allocate space for the data

tablename(i) = objLB.Name ' put data in the respective unit of array.

i = i + 1

Next

' pass the first table range to the "paste sub".
' This is where I have the problem.
' What is missing here?
rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tablename(1)).Range

End Function

Sub paste_table()

Dim rng As Variant

selecttable().Copy

Cells(10, 12).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: `selecttable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tablename(1)).Range`? you do not return anything in the function.

Comment: @ScottCraner, can you please elaborate on this? Isn't the right side of the equation a range?

Comment: `rng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tablename(1)).Range` does not return the range to the sub it returns the range to a range variable that goes no where.  It needs to be `selecttable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tablename(1)).Range` to return the range through the function.

Comment: oh sorry it should be: `Set selecttable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tablename(1)).Range`

Comment: You want *to export table data to a normal range* yet you loop through all tables (list objects) and write their names to an array. Could you explain why you would do that when the function should return a reference to one range only?

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008, i don't quite know the name of the table so I set it as a variable to pass around. First step is to index them to see my options, and then choose the tale to work with. In this case i know there is only 1 table, so I simply selected table (1).  Also I want to increase the reusability so I am trying to pack each move as a function.